# Redis not reading configuration file

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, redis

I am trying to setup a redis server following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-redis) to provide shared sessions for my Elastic Beanstalk.

I've installed redis on a new ec2 instance, and it's working fine, locally. However, when I tried to connect the project from my Beanstalk to my redis server, I am getting a "connection refused" error.

After some poking around, I found out that my redis only listens to local (I think?)

```
netstat -l
tcp        0      0 localhost:6379              *:*                         LISTEN
```

I have already out `bind 0.0.0.0` to `/etc/redis/6379.conf`, but I suspect that redis is not reading the same configuration file.

My questions:

1. How do I check if my redis server is actually loading the configuration file? I tried typing spam into the file and `sudo service redis_6379 restart` expecting errors, but redis starts normally.
2. Is there another way for me to configure redis to listen to all connections from my VPC?

**Edit: Found my answer.**

1. [To find out what configuration file is loaded](https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/205308418-How-to-install-and-use-Redis-on-Linux): `redis-cli -p 6379 info server`
2. There's 2 parts of the configuration file that I need to change, firstly `bind 0.0.0.0` and comment the `bind 127.0.0.1` that comes after.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS I was running into a similar issue after reboot of the EC2 server, for me what resolved it (my nodeJs app was running as Ubuntu user I needed to make that path available) was to add to the PATH within /etc/crontab by:

`sudo nano /etc/crontab` and just comment out the original path in there so you can switch back if required (mine was: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin ) and replace it with:

`PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.0/bin` and that error disappeared for me